# SQL Help: MS-ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I keep getting a syntax error for SQL in Microsoft ACCESS. RUNS fine in SQL developer. The error says "syntax error in FROM clause"

```
SELECT REPLACE(A.Comment, "<p><u>"," ")
FROM [Review status update] AS A INNER JOIN (Select [Review status update].ReviewID, max([Review status update].ProgressCommentDate) AS ProgressCommentDate
from [Review status update]
group by [Review status update].ReviewID
)  AS B ON (A.ProgressCommentDate = B.ProgressCommentDate) AND (A.ReviewID = B.ReviewID);
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: If with "SQL Developer" you mean Oracle, then I 100% the query will not run at all with Oracle

Comment: error is syntax error in FROM clause

Comment: I just tried your code in Access 2013 and it's fine as it is, assuming the table has the relevant fields. My only question had been whether Access would cope with the calculated field not having an alias ... but 2013 at least copes. Is the table itself in Access or is this a linked table and/or pass through query?

Comment: This line `max([Review status update].ProgressCommentDate) AS ProgressCommentDate` will cause a circular reference warning.  You'll need to alias as something different.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Access 2010`.

If your table is this:
[image]

You want to return the latest comment for each ReviewID with the `<p><u>` removed.
This SQL will return the table below:

```
SELECT      REPLACE(A.Comment, "<p><u>"," ")
FROM        [Review status update] AS A INNER JOIN 
            (
             SELECT     ReviewID
                        , MAX(ProgressCommentDate) AS MaxOfProgressCommentDate
             FROM       [Review status update]
             GROUP BY   ReviewID
            )  AS B ON (A.ProgressCommentDate = B.MaxOfProgressCommentDate) AND (A.ReviewID = B.ReviewID)
```

[image]